# Updating jQuery 1.7.1 to the latest 2.x version - What are the breaking changes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.7, jquery-2.0

I need to update jQuery 1.7.1 to the latest 2.x version. The target application contains too many scripts/plugins which should be carefully revisited to handle those breaking changes that happened though the years. However, I do not remember all those "breaking" changes, so I thought maybe someone could point me to the right direction. For example, [this document](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated) lists the deprecated functions which helps a lot but it's not enough yet.

Please note that I'm not going to target IE6/7/8 so I insist on upgrading to the latest 2.x version. Any strategy, check list or information to ease "the pain" is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is it about the lists of deprecated functions that isn't sufficient? For your migration (1.7.1 -> 2.1.1), you just need [the stuff deprecated in 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/) and [the stuff deprecated in 1.10](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.10/). There are no **API** changes between 1.x and 2.x. Obviously you'll need to make sure there the latest versions of your plugins are 2.x-compatible (not relying on things deprecated in 1.8 or 1.10).

Comment: Well, the thing is that they list deprecated functions, only. I'm interested in "breaking changes excluding deprecated functions, if any" in the existing API while migrating from 1.7.1 to 1.8, and all the way to the 2.1.1.

Comment: @ Joe: The jQuery team almost **never** create breaking changes without deprecation. I can't immediately think of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at  [this Sitepoint post](http://www.sitepoint.com/whats-new-in-jquery-2-0/) as it is a higher level explanation of the changes than just the API. These are summarised as:

- No support for IE6/7/8
- Deprecated features means code is removed and smaller download
- More modular codebase to allow the inclusion or exclusion of components.

There are a huge amount of changes, but if you aren't interested in IE6/7/8, this should be fine.

Comment: Link-only answers are not useful. At least summarize the linked content, which can rot.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing I would advise you is on using `live()`. It has been replaced by `on()`.

So, you should check for `live` code and convert to `on` code.

The other one is `.selector`. It was deprecated as accurate selector couldn't be given.

Also `size()` is deprecated. Just use `.length`